# When I click on refresh it becomes half visible

Tags: html, css, dojo

I have on my page a grid where I show log history and a refresh button ( onclick I refresh the grid with new data ).

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Log history">
    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="btn_refresh" onclick="load_logs" style="float:right; border:1px solid black;">Refresh</button>
    <div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="log" data="window.store_data_log"> </div>
    <div id="grid_log" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="log" structure="window.layout_log" queryOptions="{deep:true}" query="{}" clientSort="true" rowsPerPage="5"> </div>
</div>
```

Before [image]
After [image]

Problem is that when I click, in Chrome, my refresh button moves up and become half visible. I tried to put `<BR/>` after the button but then grid is then not visible at all. I tried to put the button in a new  but also then grid is not visible at all. What to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and decided to use dijit.layout.LayoutContainer and dijit.layout.ContentPane which has worked great. On the main content pane just set layoutAlign="client" and it will take up the remaining layout space.

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" 
     title="Log history">

     <div dojoType="dijit.layout.LayoutContainer" 
          style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" 
             layoutAlign="top" 
             style="height:28px;padding:2px;">

             <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" 
                    id="btn_refresh" 
                    onclick="load_logs"
                    style="float:right; border:1px solid black;">
             Refresh</button>

        </div>

        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" 
             layoutAlign="client" 
             style="padding:0px 2px;">

             <div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" 
                  jsId="log"    
                  data="window.store_data_log"> </div>

             <div id="grid_log" 
                  dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" 
                  store="log"   
                  structure="window.layout_log" 
                  queryOptions="{deep:true}" 
                  query="{}" 
                  clientSort="true" 
                  rowsPerPage="5"> </div>

       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```